# What is the connection between shrimp and old age?

Tags: words, kanji, etymology

Shrimp (えび) is written several different ways in Japanese. For example, there are the words commonly used in Chinese: 蝦 and 鰕. There is also a compound specific to Japan, 海老, and a kokuji, 蛯. Both of the latter contain the character for old age, 老. Is there some reason why the Japanese associate shrimp with old age?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [Japanese Wikipedia page for エビ](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%B5%B7%E8%80%81) says the following:

> 漢字表記の「海老」や「蛯」の字は曲がった腰を老人に見立てたものである。

Apparently the use of 老 comes from the way shrimp bend forward, like an old person bending forward at the waist.

Comment: Ah, I was just typing the same answer. +1 (The part before that about the relation to grapes is also interesting).

Comment: Hmm, you both beat me to it.

Comment: I heard it was because of their whiskers, that supposedly resemble old men's moustaches. Either way, it comes down to a likeness in appearance.